# Create a JSON from a list in Python

Tags: python

I have a list with a bunch of sentences, very much like below:

["Hello, how are you", "You look great today", "Your shoes are ugly", "Your momma so fat she..."]

I want to use the Azure Cognitive Services API which expects its request to be in this form:

```
{
  "documents": [
    {
      "language": "en",
      "id": "1",
      "text": "Hello, how are you"
    },
    {
      "language": "en",
      "id": "2",
      "text": "You look great today"
    },
    {
      "language": "en",
      "id": "3",
      "text": "Your momma so fat she..."
    }
  ]
}
```

I don't have any clue how to create a nested json from a flat list. I would need to have `id` be incremented for each element in the list and `language` be `en` for every item in the list.

Any help or links would be appreciated

Comment: Have you tried [a `for` loop](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I am missing something about your question, it would probably be easiest to just iterate through your array when creating the JSON you need. Python lets you create arrays like:

```
[something(i) for i in someArray]
```

For your example you could probably do something like:

```
yourText = ["There is text", "in this array", "please convert it!"]

yourJSON = {"documents" : [{ "language" : "en", "id" : str(idx + 1), "text": val} for idx, val in enumerate(array)]}
```

Comment: Holy Smokes man, that worked exactly as I needed to. Thank you for the help. You're super smart!